# VsVim does not keep macro after Visual Studio restart

Tags: vim, vsvim

When I enter a macro and run it, it works fine.
Unfortunately after I restart Visual Studio all macros are gone. How to prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other vim implementations, like gVim, preserve register values across restarts.  Macros are stored as register values hence they get persisted as well.  That feature though hasn't been implemented in VsVim yet.

This bug is tracking that: https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/issues/1726